# DOS FOR /F Syntax Error

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a text file 'infos.txt' that I am parsing with a FOR /F statement.  Under windows DOS environment this works as intended, but my target is Native DOS. When run from a DOS environment I receive a syntax error.  I have written it with %i  %%i to no avail.  This should be pretty simple.  Any clues?  Again, this does work as intended from a CMD prompt in windows, but neither in VirtualBox DOS or Booting to DOS via USB and running the bat file.

My delimiter is =

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in (infos.txt) do echo.%%i
```

Comment: The DOS help system should tell you what's available if you type "help" or "help for".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FOR /F` is an NT enhancement not available on DOS.

Comment: Well then I guess I can stop trying to make this work.  All the resources I looked at indicated this to be a feature of DOS.  Thanks for the quick reply .